# Error with OnClickListener in my gallery

Tags: java, android, eclipse, onclick, gallery

Hi I have problem with `ImageButton` "strzalkaLewo" when i setOnClickListener i have this error in logCat:

enter

```
    pozycjaZdjecia = bundle.getInt("zdjecie");
     imgPath = ExternalStorageDirectoryPath
            + "/DailyPhotos/"+nazwa_projektu;  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.pokaz_slajdow);    

    strzalkaLewo = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.strzalkal);

    strzalkaLewo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "msg msg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    });

    photoList = readFileList();    
    imageSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher)findViewById(R.id.switcher);    
    imageSwitcher.setFactory(this);    
    /*  
     *   
     */    
    imageSwitcher.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,      
            android.R.anim.fade_in));      
    imageSwitcher.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,      
            android.R.anim.fade_out));    
    imageSwitcher.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);    
    gallery = (Gallery)findViewById(R.id.gallery);    

    gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter( photoList,this));    
    gallery.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {    
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,    
                int position, long when) {    
            newFilePath = photoList.get(position);    
            Bitmap bm = decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(photoList.get(position), 480,
                    360);
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "msg msg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           // Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoList.get(position));    
            BitmapDrawable bd = new BitmapDrawable(bm);    
            imageSwitcher.setImageDrawable(bd);    
        }    
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}    
    });    

    gallery.setSelection(pozycjaZdjecia, true);




}
```

Also I use OnTouchListener to switch between images:

```
enter  private OnTouchListener touchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {    
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {    



         if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)     //lokalizacja poczatkowa. 
            {     
                downX=(int) event.getX();//      

                return true;
            }      
            else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)      //lokalizacja zakonczona
            {      
                upX=(int) event.getX();//      
                int index = 0;      
                if(upX-downX>60)//?      
                {      
                    //?      
                    if(gallery.getSelectedItemPosition()==0)      
                       index=gallery.getCount()-1;      
                    else      
                        index=gallery.getSelectedItemPosition()-1;      
                }      
                else if(downX-upX>60)//?      
                {      
                    //?      
                    if(gallery.getSelectedItemPosition()==(gallery.getCount()-1))      
                        index=0;    

                    else      
                        index=gallery.getSelectedItemPosition()+1;      
                }
```

**LogCat:**

```
09-18 11:52:18.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6397): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-18 11:52:18.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6397): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-18 11:52:18.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at com.example.dailyphotos.GaleriaImg$1.onTouch(GaleriaImg.java:133)
09-18 11:52:18.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7122)
09-18 11:52:18.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2170)
09-18 11:52:18.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1905)
09-18 11:52:18.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
09-18 11:52:18.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1877)
09-18 11:52:18.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
09-18 11:52:18.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1877)
09-18 11:52:18.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
09-18 11:52:18.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1877)
09-18 11:52:18.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
09-18 11:52:18.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1877)
09-18 11:52:18.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1925)
09-18 11:52:18.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1379)
09-18 11:52:18.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2396)
09-18 11:52:18.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1873)
09-18 11:52:18.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7307)
09-18 11:52:18.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3172)
09-18 11:52:18.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3117)
09-18 11:52:18.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4153)
09-18 11:52:18.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4132)
09-18 11:52:18.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4224)
09-18 11:52:18.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
09-18 11:52:18.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
09-18 11:52:18.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
09-18 11:52:18.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
09-18 11:52:18.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
09-18 11:52:18.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-18 11:52:18.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-18 11:52:18.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-18 11:52:18.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-18 11:52:18.888: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Are there any more lines to the exception? The error is most likely that findViewById(R.id.gallery) is returning null, but I cannot tell from the code posted.